# How does one choose the bandwidth for the confidence intervals of a kernel density estimate?

Tags: confidence-interval, kernel-smoothing

My lecturer estimated a kernel density, then wanted to give confidence intervals for it. So, he used a bandwidth $$h_c = h_g \times \frac 1{n^{0.05}}$$ where $h_g$ was the bandwidth of the original kernel estimator, $n$ is the sample size, and $0.05$ is the level of significance, then used $$\hat f_c(x) \pm 1.96\times\sqrt{\frac 1{nh_c}\times \hat f_c(x)\int K^2(\psi)\,\mathrm d\psi} $$ as the confidence intervals, where $\hat f_c$ is the kernel estimate from using the bandwidth $h_c$. I understand that a smaller bandwidth is needed due to the bias in the original kernel estimator (and the variance of the confidence intervals don't matter as those are not reported).

**Was the calculation $h_c = h_g \times \frac 1{n^{0.05}}$ just a rule of thumb, or was it chosen optimally?** If it was chosen optimally, please explain the rationale for it. Would the formula be $$h_c = h_g \times \frac 1{n^p}$$ where $p$ stands for the level of significance?